# How to Use MVVMCross6 with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm embarking on a project that would benefit from the use of a MVVM framework. After conducting basic research, I chose MVVMCross over others.

The trouble is, like many other frameworks, MVVMCross has steep learning curve with not so much helpful (and sometimes confusing) documentation and tutorials.

MVVMCross6 was recently released with a number of improvements making it ideal for a beginner to start with. The unfortunate issue with this new release is that there are a lot of breaking changes which made existing documentations and tutorials unsuitable and even more confusing.

Documentation on MVVMCross website on the new release is rather limited and insufficient.

I've tried frantically to apply some old tutorials on previous version 5.x without any success. For instance, this tutorial - https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/12/27/Getting-Started-MvvmCross-with-Xamarin-Forms-(Part-2).aspx - would have been just perfect for my situation but for the differences. I followed it up until creating the Setup.cs stage then some breaking changes' errors which make the rest of the tutorial irrelevant.

What I need now to get going with the pending project is a basic step-by-step guide on how to setup a first time HelloWorld Xamarin.Forms with MVVMCross6. I could handle the rest from that point on.

Please, can any seasoned user of MVVMCross framework guide me on how to jump this initial setup's hurdle and get started using MVVMCross6 immediately?

I would be highly grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look to this official docs [TipCalc Xamarin.Forms](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version?scroll=1885) and [Upgrade from 5 to MvvmCross 6](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60)

Comment: Yes, thanks. The suggestion on the question was helpful to some extents but not detailed enough.